# Is it possible to turn off magic quotes without an .htaccess or a php.ini file?

Tags: php, backslash, magic-quotes, modx-evolution

One of my clients is hosting their site on freeservers.com ( a host that should be avoided at all costs ).

The host does not allow .htaccess files, and has no editable php.ini file on the server to edit.

But it does have magic_quotes on. Which is destroying all my POST requests.

What options do I have to turn this off still?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: MagicQuotes hurts, doesn't it? :)

Comment: ha! I'm a Rails guy. Just started playing with PHP. I guess this is one of those de'virgin'ing milestones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to turn off magic quotes without an .htaccess or a php.ini file?

No.

> Which is destroying all my POST requests.

Not a big deal.
To loop over $_POST array and strip slashes is a function of scarcely 5 lines, even with recursion.
Or you can google for the magic quotes and get this ready, I believe.  It was posted thousands times here already, you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can still turn off it in PHP script using [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

like this

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc',"0");
```

But disabling or enabling magic quotes with ini_set in PHP 5.3.0 is Deprecated.

Comment: There is no point in doing this, because by the time you are in a position to do it, GPC variables have already been filtered.

Comment: and `ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', false);` - though I've never quite figured out why the PHP manual says it's a `boolean` and that the default value is "0" (string "0") - which has to be the worst `false` equivalent I've ever seen ;)

Comment: Note this is only for PHP < 5.3.0.

Comment: @Hammerite - oh yeah *facepalm* didn't think that through before commenting :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PHP before.. but I found that if I put a php.ini file in any directory where PHP is receiving a POST request.. and put this line in it.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Problem solved! No .htaccess and no root php.ini file..

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php - intriguing, utterly useless for anyone with PHP compiled into Apache - but interesting nonetheless. I've certainly never encountered (nor had a need for) this functionality.